# Wrong publishing date

Tags: citation-style

Hej  I´ve just got a new scientific paper published and have discovered that it is wrong publication year

Thies-Lagergren, L., Kvist, L. J., Gottvall, K., & Jangsten, E. **(1920)**. A Swedish register-based study exploring primary postpartum hemorrhage in 405 936 full term vaginal births between 2005 and 2015. European Journal of Obstetrics & Gynecology and Reproductive Biology.

It should be Thies-Lagergren, L., Kvist, L. J., Gottvall, K., & Jangsten, E. (**2021**). A Swedish register-based study exploring primary postpartum hemorrhage in 405 936 full term vaginal births between 2005 and 2015. European Journal of Obstetrics & Gynecology and Reproductive Biology.

When searching on Google Scholar it will not show under publication year 2021 only when combing my name + PPH it will show and you see the date 1920 which means it is far back in the publication line if you understand...

How can this be amended?

Important as I want my results to be known!

Greetings Li

Comment: I downloaded the pdf and see that the year is 2021. Can you clarify where you got that 1920?

Comment: *I "have discovered that it is wrong publication year"* - Where did you discover this? In someone's citation? On google scholar? In your library catalogue?

Comment: When searching on Google Scholar it will not show under publication year 2021 only when combing my name + PPH  it will show and you see the date 1920 which means it is far back in the publication line if you understand.....

Comment: When searching on Google Scholar, it now shows 2021. Please try it yourself. Next time, if it happens, the first thing to do is to notify Google, let them correct it.

Answer (score 2):

If you see any wrong metadata about your published article, the first persons you should address are the editors of the journal.

However, in your case, I do not see the wrong year you claim to see. Where is it that you encountered it?

The metadata to your paper are correctly documented (at *CrossRef*). See the `date`-field [here](https://api.crossref.org/works/10.1016/j.ejogrb.2020.12.018):

[image: CrossRef JSON with correct date]

In addition, both the [website](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejogrb.2020.12.018) at Elsevier and the PDF-version seem to name the correct year as well:
[image: Elsevier website with correct date]
[image: Elsevier PDF]